# NAs occuring in the output of logistic regression (using multinom) in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm trying to perform logistic regression using `multinom()` of `nnet` package over the following data using R:
[Train Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bznk6HkWGRBYZ3ZIZzNrdE11TjQ/edit?usp=sharing)
[Test Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bznk6HkWGRBYczNXeFl5cGxMNGc/edit?usp=sharing)

#### Data Description:

Each of the train and test files have 10,000 rows of data and 144 variables, where the last column is "Predict", which is the column that should be predicted in the test data. Since, predict contains only two values 0 and 1 (binary), I started with fitting the train data to a logistic regression model using `multinom()`. Most of the rows are continuous numeric values, while a few fields contains name fields like names of a weekdays ("Sunday", "Monday", ...), which are to be considered as factors.

This is the following code used:

```
train_data <- read.csv("train_data.csv")
test_data <- read.csv("test_data.csv")
library(nnet)
my_multinom <- multinom(formula= as.factor(Predict) ~ ., data= train_data)
predictions <- predict(my_multinom, test_data[,1:143])
```

And the output is:

```
> summary(predictions)
   0    1   NA's 
 130   52   9818
```

where as, there are no `NA's` in the `Predict` column of the `train_data`:

```
> summary(as.factor(train_data$Predict))
   0    1 
9734  266
```

I want to know what is the reason for the occurrence of such a huge amount of `NA's` (more than 98%) and how to proceed further so that I could avoid these `NA's`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your test data. Each row, where the prediction is `NA`, contains an `NA` value:

```
all(apply(sapply(test_data[is.na(predictions),1:143], is.na),1,any))
#[1] TRUE
```

The other rows don't contain any `NA` values:

```
any(apply(sapply(test_data[!is.na(predictions),1:143], is.na),1,any))
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland . That worked.
Is there any function for logistic regression where an output is predicted even though there are a few `NA` in the input rows?

Comment: That's impossible without imputation.